# Hex, Dec, Byte conversion of NFC UID with python3

Tags: python, type-conversion, nfc

I am very confused about the UID reading of NFC tags.

I have an ACR122U NFC reader (not sure if relevant) set up with pynfc. I have one tag (TagType2), if I use grab the UID using `tag.identifier.hex()` which is mentioned in the docs I get `c9ccd97b` which I think the string representation of the UID.

I also have another simple NFC UID reader machine, which pastes the UID of the tag and presses enter. I dont exactly know its type, but I know for certain that it is only able to read 4 bytes.

If i use the same tag with said UID reader I get `2ö778713ö5` which looks weird. I tried to convert `c9ccd97b` it to bytes, and obtain the first 4 bytes using `stringIO` of python, but when I go back to string I dont get `2ö778713ö5`

Any idea what kind of conversion steps should I make so I can see that the tag is in face the same with these two devices?

EDIT: If I plug the simple reader into a windows machine I get 2077871305 so ö=0. I also found a small exe which with I can change the read type. If i set it to "8 no. in HEX reverse" I get `c9ccd97b` which is the desired output, however I dont know what "8 no. in HEX reverse", and have no idea how to make this transformation in python

Comment: '\xc9\xcc\xd9\x7b'  would probably be how to represent c9ccd97b in 4 bytes

Comment: A type 2 UID is either 4, 7 or 10 bytes long.  The number you've given seems suspicious.  Is it possible your "simple NFC UID reader" is reading the contents, and not the UID?  Do you know exactly what model tag you have?

Comment: @TimRoberts All I get from pynfc is Type2Tag. I was able to pinpoint a little further. If I plug the simple reader into a windows machine I get `2077871305` so ö=0. I also found a small exe which with I can change the read type. If i set it to "8 no. in HEX reverse" I get `c9ccd97b` which is the desired output. I ll edit my question accordingly

Comment: And did you try converting that?  `2077871305` in hex is `7bd9ccc9`.  It's the same number, just with different big-endian/little-endian interpretation.  So, what now is your problem?  If you're just trying to collect UIDs, then you don't really care whether they are big-endian or little-endian.  As long as the same app reads them, you just need a number.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am sorry that the part I am missing. I have no idea these sadly. I guess I somehow need to reverse `7bd9ccc9`, but I have no idea how.

Comment: WHY DO YOU NEED TO REVERSE IT?  What's the matter with just using the number you get?

Comment: @TimRoberts I dont know if I have to reverse it or not. So the NFC reader gets `2077871305` which is `7bd9ccc9` in hex. However the other reader gets `c9ccd97b`. I think these two hex number are related somehow. From the "8 no. in HEX reverse" message I thought they are reversed somehow, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Of COURSE they are the same number.  Can't you see that the bytes are just in reversed?  `7b d9 cc c9` vs `c9 cc d9 7b`?  What I'm saying is, as long as your script always gets one or the other, it doesn't matter what ordering you use.  You'll always recognize the tag.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts THANKS A LOT!!! Sorry I have very little experience with binary, hexadecimal and other stuff, but I see it now! If put this in an answer I ll be more than happy to upvote the hell out of it!

Comment: So usually when an old style reader reads just 4 bytes of a 7 byte UID it just reads the first 4 bytes and also some readers return the UID is reverse order to others. For NFC it does not matter which way around they are as they just have to be different when multiple cards are presented at the same time, they are not Unique (Really the U of UID is for Unit ID not U for Unique)